# How to calculate file upload and download time using asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I have a scenario in which need to calculate the Server Time for uploading files as per the Connection speed.

**Example:**

> Need to calculate time to upload files with Connection speed 256Kbps and more
>   If connection breaks then checking the remaining time and restart the download or upload operation where it was break

Answer (score 2):

256 Kbps = 32 kilobyte per second = 32768 bytes / s.

The size of your file is x bytes. So it takes (x / 32768) seconds.

If the connection is broken, you should query what was the last byte received by the receiver, put your filestream tot that position and continue.

Comment: Can you elaborate the same, I know the logic but dont know how to apply. Its good if you will supply the asp.net C# code. To calculate elapsed time, remaining time etc.